# specify path to pdf in node.js project that can be reached when deployed

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-platform

I am deploying a `node.js` website on Google cloud platform, and I would like my keep my resume there, which is currently in my local directory. My code is as follows:

```
import { Router }   from 'express';
import * as express from 'express';
import * as path    from 'path'   ;
import * as pug     from 'pug'    ;
import * as fs from 'fs';

const index: Router = Router();


index.get('/curriculum-vitae', (req, res, next) => { 

    var pdf_path = "local/path/to/resume.pdf"   

    fs.readFile( pdf_path, (err, data) =>{
        res.contentType('application/pdf');
        res.send(data)
    })
});
```

However, I would like to change `pdf_path` to relative path so that when I deploy the app it can be found on the remote server. It is not clear how to do so since `fs.readFile` seem to only take absolute paths.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the documentation for [`fs`](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/path.html#path_path_dirname_path):

> String form paths are interpreted as UTF-8 character sequences identifying the absolute or relative filename. Relative paths will be resolved relative to the current working directory as specified by process.cwd().

So relative paths *are* supported, but from the directory from which `node` was invoked.

If you're looking to use a path relative to the current JS source file instead, use [`__dirname`](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/modules.html#modules_dirname). For accessing the project root folder, just `..` your way up starting from `__dirname` till you reach the project root. This will always work because your source structure isn't going to change.